# Unable to output ArrayList contents

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I'm reading a txt file wich contains one word in each line, stripping the word from non-alphanumeric characters and storing the results into an Array List.

```
public class LeeArchivo 
{   

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    try
    {   

        BufferedReader lector = null;
        List<String> matrix  = new ArrayList<String>();

        lector = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("spanish.txt"));
        String line = null;

        while((line = lector.readLine())!=null)
        {
            //matrix.add(line);
            matrix.add((line.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']").toString()));     
        }   

        System.out.println(matrix);
        System.out.println(matrix.size());
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

when I try to print the contents of the ArrayList all I get is each String Object's memory address. The funny thing is, if I don't split the line ie.: I just matrix.add(line) I get the Strings Ok. 
I've tried StringBuilders, Iterators, .toString but nothing works.
Can somebody help me to understand what's going on here?
Thanks.

Comment: Why the extra set of parens inside the add method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `line.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']")` call returns a String array. Not a String.
So, you are adding not a String instance to your array list, but the result of String array object toString() method call - the String array object's memory address.

If you need to get the whole string after splitting, you should concatenate all
elements of the array, for example:

```
while((line = lector.readLine())!=null) {

    String[] arr = line.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']");
    String res = "";

    for(String s : arr) {
        res += s;
    }

    matrix.add(res);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks I understand now. but if I don't call the toString() method call I get an error in matrix.add() Says: The method add(String) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String[]) How can I go about this?

Comment: Thak you that does it.

Comment: Why is the toString() still after the split?

Comment: @Rob Right you are. My bad. Corrected.